# Find blocks of data in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a table with series of measurements done by some  modules, let's call them N and W.
Each row contains one measurement.
I want to assign an unique block identifier to each measurement, see expected output below.

**Assumption:** records in table are written in some order based on time and module, therefore one can assume, that ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) delivers an ordering column.

How can I do this in Hive?

Expected output:

```
+---------+-------+
| module  | block |
+---------+-------+
| W       |   1   |
| W       |   1   |
| W       |   1   |
| N       |   2   |
| N       |   2   |
| W       |   3   |
| W       |   3   |
| W       |   3   |
+---------+-------+
```

Sample data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS so_sample;
CREATE TABLE so_sample (
  module string
);
INSERT INTO TABLE so_sample
VALUES ("W"), ("W"), ("W"), ("N"), ("N"), ("W"), ("W"), ("W")
;
```

Regards
Paweł

Comment: is there a column to specify the *row order*?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no column, which specifies explicitely row order.

Comment: With out a ordering column what you are asking is impossible to do.

Comment: One can add such a column using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1), would it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: build a block identifier from a module name and a number made by subtracting row number within a certain module from global row number.

Block identifier is unique and additionally preserves order of blocks within a module:

```
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT 
    module,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as row_nr
  FROM so_sample
  )
SELECT 
  module,
  row_nr,
  module || 
    cast(
        row_nr - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY module ORDER BY row_nr)
        AS STRING ) as block_id
FROM ordered
ORDER BY row_nr
;
```

Regards
Paweł